# Output X number of asterisks based on an attribute value

Tags: xslt-1.0

#### Output value X number of times.

This problem escapes me repeatedly and I usually handle it the way I show here, but I am tired of doing things incorrectly and want to learn a better way to do this.

This below code demonstrates what I'm trying to achieve, but I don't want to write all of this. I have a variable (`$ast`) that will output the number of asterisks I want. Surely this can be done in a more simple way.

```
<xsl:when test="$itm_lev = 0" >
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($itm_lev)"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$itm_lev = 1" >
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($ast,$itm_lev)"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$itm_lev = 2" >
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($ast,$ast,$itm_lev)"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$itm_lev = 3" >
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($ast,$ast,$ast,$itm_lev)"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$itm_lev = 4" >
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($ast,$ast,$ast,$ast,$itm_lev)"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$itm_lev = 5" >
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($ast,$ast,$ast,$ast,$ast,$itm_lev)"/>
</xsl:when>
```

Output:

```
    0
    *1
    **2
    ***3
    ****4
    *****5
```

Comment: >I should have said asterisks not spaces in the title. My apology.

Comment: Is there a maximum number of asterisks you will ever need?

Comment: It should theoretically never exceed ten,,,,but I do not want to limit it to 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three options for your consideration:

**1.**

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring('********************', 1, $itm_lev)"/>
```

Requires presetting a maximum of asterisks (= the length of the string of asterisks above) ;

**2.**

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(math:power(10, $itm_lev) - 1, '90', '*')"/>
```

Requires a processor that supports the EXSLT math:power() extension function (most do). Note that depending on your specific processor, this may bomb when $itm_lev > 15;

**3.**

Call a recursive named template.

Comment: I am unsure how to credit you with a quality answer yet but I will read how and do so. Yhe first answer you gave was great. It is simple effective afficient and works great. Thank you sir!

Comment: This is what did it nicely thanks to michael                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring('************',1, $itm_lev),$itm_lev)"/>